# Localizar E Substituir Várias Palavra Dentro De Um Arquivo

Tags: linux, script, bash, shell, unix

Quero desenvolver um `script` que fará a substituição de quaisquer palavras no *arquivo*.

Sei que posso fazer com o(s) comando(s) abaixo:

`$ tr 'ABC' '123' < arquivo.txt > novo-arquivo.txt`

ou

`$ sed "s/ABC/123/g" arquivo.txt > novo-arquivo.txt`

Entretanto não desejo apenas fazer a simples troca de uma "palavra" por "outra", mas sim, fazer várias mudança de várias "*palavras*" dentro do arquivo(documento)

## Por Exemplo:

> Gostaria que o `script` realizasse substituição em ***massa .. grupo/conjunto*** *palavras* que venha a ser definida pelo próprio usuário.

Suponhamos que o arquivo(documento) contenha as seguintes palavras:

- homen
- sol
- dia

Então o `script` deveria fazer a pergunta sobre as devidas troca, algo assim:

1) - Digite aqui, todas palavras na qual você deseja substitui-las: **homen, sol, dia**

2) - Agora, digite na mesma ordem anterior, as novas a serem inseridas: **mulher, lua, noite**

> Isto é, automatizar alteração de modo geral, ao invés de substituir apenas uma única palavra, pode-ser mais de uma em diferentes ocorrência.

## Conclusão

Então bastaria ser definido pelo usuário,  para efetuar a troca no próprio *arquivo* de modo simultâneo (de uma só vez). Mudar um **conjunto de palavras** por **outras** que o próprio usuário poderá definir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obter as palavras a serem substituídas a partir da entrada do usuário e colocar num `array`, faça assim:

```
palavras=()
while IFS= read -r -p "Digite a palavra ([ENTER] para terminar): " linha; do
    [[ $linha ]] || break
    palavras+=("$linha")
done
```

Supondo que você tenha os `arrays` de palavras a serem substituídas e os substitutos:

```
substituir=( "homem" "sol" "dia" )
substituto=( "mulher" "lua" "noite" )
```

Use um laço `for` para iterar sobre um dos `arrays`, e com o `sed` você faz a substituição:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#substituir[@]}; ++i)); do
    printf "Substituindo ${substituir[i]} por ${substituto[i]}...\n"

    sed -i "s/${substituir[i]}/${substituto[i]}/" foo.txt
done
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMT0ZhMU1yYkNJbGc)</kbd>

<sub>**Nota**: Se você precisar que seja feita a substituição de forma global, adicione o modificador `g` após o segundo delimitador.</sub>

Também é possível usar o Perl, em uma linha:

```
perl -i -pe 's/homem/mulher/g; s/sol/lua/g; s/dia/noite/g' foo.txt
```

A opção `i` indica basicamente que será feito alterações no arquivo. `p` é usado para iterar sobre o arquivo, `e` indica o código a ser executado, neste caso `s/.../...`. [**Mais informações**](http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/08/09/commandline.html).

Comment: Com sed  também dá pra usar uma linha: sed -i -e 's/..../.../; s/.../.../;...'

Answer (score 3):

## Teste(Requer Terminal/Console - Linux/Unix)

Crie um *arquivo* de texto, com os seguintes conteúdo: **homen**, **dia**, **sol**.

Agora, abra seu terminal console, cole ou digite o comando abaixo:

```
for troca in `cat teste.txt`; do echo "$(sed 's/homen/mulher/ ; s/dia/noite/ ; s/sol/lua/' teste.txt)" > teste.txt; $troca; done
```

## Explicando

O Laço `for` irá passar as coordenadas para o comando `cat` "Ler arquivo" quando invocado a *váriavel* `$troca`, e logo "executar ação para cada linha" via `sed`, neste ponto, note que coloquei-o `sed` numa éspecie de *subshell* envolvido entre *parenteses*.

> A vantagem disso é que ***não precisamos criar um novo arquivo de saída***, ja atualizando apenas o ***arquivo original***.

**Enfim** - Me reservei no direito de apresentar apenas uma linha e só. Já é o núcleo principal para o propósito aqui.